# How do you get custom intellisense comments to appear when using a custom DLL in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments, intellisense

I have been wondering how to setup intellisense comments for Visual Studio (minimum version 2013) and have been having trouble. Using XML comments are only useful for generating the separate file for documentation.

What I want is to be able to put descriptions on functions/methods that show up when I hover over them in a project I am working that includes the DLL that should have these descriptions already set. This is something trivial to be honest but it would be really nice to have this functionality. But every thing I try seems to end with no comments being shown in the project when I hover over these functions/methods.

To restate my question, what needs to be done to allow for my descriptions of functions/methods to appear when I hover over them when they are used in a separate project/solution?

Comment: Not exactly sure what "Using XML comments are only useful for generating the separate file for documentation." means, but that resulting XML file is exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: I've used them for a bit now but they still do not show up in other projects. I can never see them. Is it because I need to change a build setting? It was recommended but I wasn't too sure.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I got it to work. I just checked the XML documentation file box in Project Properties -> Build Tab. I also needed to include it as Alexei Levenkov helped me out with in the comments. Doing both of those things allow them to show up.